# If $\int_X f d\mu = M$, then there $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) \ge M$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $X$. Let $f \in L_1(X, \mu, \mathbb R)$ such that $\int f d\mu = M$.

> Can we show that there is $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) \ge M$?

**My attempt:**

Clearly, $\int f d \mu > M-1/n$ for all $n$. If $f(x) \le M-1/n$ for all $x \in X$, then $\int f d \mu \le M-1/n$, which is a contradiction. Hence there is $x_n \in X$ such that $f(x_n) > M-1/n$. After this, I got stuck.

Could you elaborate if above statement is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose that for every $x \in X$, one has $f(x) < M$. Then the function $x \mapsto M-f(x)$ is positive, so for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, you have by Markov's inequality
$$\mu \left( \left\lbrace x \in X \mid M-f(x) \geq \dfrac{1}{n}\right\rbrace\right) \leq n \int_X (M-f(x)) d\mu(x) = 0 $$

Taking the union, you get that $$\mu \left( \left\lbrace x \in X \mid M-f(x) \geq 0\right\rbrace\right)=0$$ which contradicts the fact that $f(x)<M$ for every $x$.

Comment: why is the last term in the first inequality equal to 0?

Comment: @NickCastillo Because $\int f d\mu= M$, so $\int (M-f) d\mu = 0$.

Comment: Ahh of course, thanks

Comment: I believe the inequality will be strict, while considering the measure-zero set at the end of the solution above.