# A Simple Example of a Function on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I am looking for a concrete example of a continuous function $f$ on the unit interval $[0, 1]$ such that $0\leq f(x) <1$ for each $x\in [0, 1]$, but $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Such a function does not exist (even if you remove the continuity assumption).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe What is the proof in the non-continuous case?

Comment: @JairTaylor Assume that such a function exists : you can quickly get a contradiction using Markov's inequality. See for example my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452802/if-int-x-f-d-mu-m-then-there-x-0-in-x-such-that-fx-0-ge-m/4452812#4452812).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That was helpful, thanks! Can your answer be amended in a way that answers similar questions when $f$ is a complex valued function taking values in the closed unit disc, to answer this question for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460016/need-help-in-reasoning-with-extremal-points ?

Comment: @CarlButcher I gave you a hint for your linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function.
EDIT: as Greg Martin points out, my original answer was a bit silly. One should just say that any continuous function on a closed interval achieves its maximum. Since $f(x)<1$, this maximum $M$ is also less than $1$, and

$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx < \int_0^1 Mdx = M < 1$$

---

(original answer:)

Since $f(x) < 1$ for any $x$, $1 - f(x)$ is a positive function for $x\in[0,1]$. Any continuous function on a closed interval has a minimum, so for some number $\epsilon$ we have $1 - f(x) > \epsilon$. Rearrange to get $f(x) < 1 - \epsilon$.

Then the integral is similarly bounded:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx < \int_0^1 (1-\epsilon) dx = 1 - \epsilon$$

Comment: There's no need to subtact from $1$ twice; one can argue directly with the maximum of the original function. Consider streamlining this answer?

Answer (score 5):

No such function exists.

Suppose by way of contradiction that such a function existed. Let $c\in (0,1).$ Then $0\leq f(c)<1.$ Furthermore, $f$ is continuous, which means $\exists\ 0<\delta<c$ such that

$$ \left\vert x-c \right\vert < \delta \implies \left\vert f(x)-f(c) \right\vert< \frac{1-f(c)}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

But this implies that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) dx \leq 1 - \left(\frac{1-f(c)}{2}\right)2\delta<1.$

Comment: I don't understand downvotes of this answer. This is ok.

Comment: @MarekKryspin I am inclined to agree.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got this (I'm not the downvoter btw). Namely, for $x \in \langle c-\delta, c+\delta\rangle \cap [0,1]$ we have
$$f(x) \le f(c) + \frac{1-f(c)}2 = \frac{1+f(c)}2 < 1$$
and then we have
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,dx &= \int_{\langle c-\delta, c+\delta\rangle \cap [0,1]}f(x)\,dx + \int_{[0,1]\setminus \langle c-\delta, c+\delta\rangle}f(x)\,dx\\
&\le 2\delta \cdot  \frac{1+f(c)}2 + 1-2\delta\\
&< 2\delta + 1 - 2\delta\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Comment: @mechanodroid you were right that it should be $\left(\frac{1-f(c)}{2}\right)2\delta$ rather than $\left(\frac{1-f(c)}{2}\right)\delta$ and I have amended this in my answer. In regards to "how i got this"... Comparing to what you have done: you have summed over the integral from $0$ to $1$ which you showed works also. I looked at what certainly was *not* under the curve of $f(x)$ and took that away from $1.$ Does this make sense now?