# The existence of uncountable product of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to generalize [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549921/the-existence-of-product-probability-measure-on-a-countable-product-of-probabili) theorem. I'm mot sure if the generalization is indeed true, and if my proof is correct. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $(\Omega_i, \mathcal{F}_i, \mu_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of probability spaces. Here $I$ is **uncountable**. Let $\Omega :=\prod_i \Omega_i$ and $\bigotimes_i \mathcal{F}_i$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that all projection maps $\pi_i: \Omega \to \Omega_i$ are measurable. Let
$$
\mathcal C := \left\{ \prod_i C_i \,\middle\vert\, C_i \in \mathcal F_i, \text{the set } \{i \in I \mid C_i \neq \Omega_i\} \text{ is finite}  \right\}.
$$

Then $\mathcal C$ is an algebra on $\Omega$ and
$$
\bigotimes_i \mathcal{F}_i = \sigma (\mathcal C).
$$

We define $\nu: \mathcal C \to [0, 1]$ as follows. For $C = \prod_i C_i \in \mathcal C$, there is a finite subset $J$ of $I$ such that $C_i = \Omega_i$ for all $i \notin J$. Let $\nu (C) := \prod_{i \in J} \nu_i (C_i)$.  Clearly, $\nu$ is finitely additive. Let's prove that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.

Let $(C_n) \subset \mathcal C$ be a decreasing sequence such that $C_n \searrow \emptyset$. It suffices to prove that $\inf_n \nu (C_n) =0$. We assume $C_n = \prod_i C_{n,i}$. Let $I_n := \{ i \in I \mid C_{n, i} \neq \Omega_i \}$. Then $I_n$ is finite for all $n$. Let $J := \bigcup_n I_n$. Then $J$ is a countable subset of $I$. Let $C_n' := \prod_{i \in J} C_{n,i}$ for all $n$. Here we have the same situation as in [the case where $I$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549921/the-existence-of-product-probability-measure-on-a-countable-product-of-probabili). This completes the proof.

---

**Remark:** The proof of $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ is inspired by this [note](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Esengupta/7360f09/kolmogorov.pdf) in which the author uses the following lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{A}$ a non-empty collection of subsets of $X$, and $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. Then for any $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ there is a countable subset $\mathcal{A}^{\prime}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $A \in \sigma\left(\mathcal{A}^{\prime}\right)$.

Comment: Proving new theorems can be a lonesome business. Can you relate the theorems of yours to the well-known [Kolmogorov extenstion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem#General_form_of_the_theorem)? Are your results stronger / weaker or, god forbit, in conflict with that ?

Comment: @KurtG. It seems to me the general form of Kolmogorov extension theorem requires a topological structure on $\Omega_i$, while mine does not. That's why I'm not sure if my generalization is correct or not.

Comment: It has been a while that I studied Kolmogorov in detail. It looks like your $\nu$ is only defined on that algebra ${\cal C}$. Even if $\nu$ is $\sigma$-additive, can it be extended so easily to a measure on $\sigma({\cal C})\,.?$ Was that not the hard part of the Kolmogorov proof where the topological properties came in ?

Comment: @KurtG. Ahh I use [Carathéodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem#Introductory_statement).

Comment: Your theorem is true, albeit I am not sure if the proof is that simple. See §9 in [Heinz Bauer, *Probability Theory*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Probability_Theory/IxrBdh0ilK8C?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=heinz+bauer+probability&printsec=frontcover) (the proof there is much longer). Kolmogorov's theorem is a bit different because -as we know- $W_t$ is not independent of $W_s$. In other words, the Wiener measure is not a product measure.

Comment: To me there seems a gap in the proof of yours. Is ${\cal C}$ really an algebra (in particular closed under finite unions)? If $I=\{1,2,3\}$ it is simpler to visualize what ${\cal C}$'s elements are: Cartesian products of the form $A\times B\times C$. I don't think that the union of two such products is always of that form.

Comment: @KurtG. Please see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548880/the-finite-cartesian-product-of-algebras-is-an-algebra).

Comment: This looks just wrong even in the case ${\cal F}(2)$. The Cartesian product of two algebras is not an algebra for the same reason that the Cartesisan product of two $\sigma$-algebras is [not a $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31000/cartesian-product-of-two-sigma-algebras-is-generally-not-a-sigma-algebra).

Comment: Thank you so much @KurtG. You're totally right! My definition of $\mathcal C$ is wrong,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My definition of $\mathcal C$ does **not** imply that $\mathcal C$ is an algebra on $\Omega$. Instead, it should be defined as
$$
\mathcal C := \left \{ A \times \prod_{i \notin J} \Omega_i \,\middle\vert\, J \text{ a finite subset of } I, A \in \bigotimes_{i \in J} \mathcal F_i \right \}.
$$

Then definition of $\nu: \mathcal C \to [0, \infty)$ is adjusted accordingly. If $C = A \times \prod_{i \notin J} \Omega_i$ with $J$ a finite subset of $I$ and $A \in \bigotimes_{i \in J} \mathcal F_i$, then
$$
\nu (C) := (\otimes_{i \in J} \mu_i) (C).
$$

Comment: This set ${\cal C}$ that you want to be an algebra looks strange. If $I$ were $\{1,2,3\}$ it looks like the sets $A\times\Omega_\color{red}{2}\times\Omega_3$ and $B\times\Omega_\color{red}{1}\times\Omega_3$ are part of it ? If so the second set is not part of $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_3$. ***Order matters***. BTW: If it were all that simple the proof of Bauer I mentioned above were way too complicated. Knowing him personally I can however assure that he was not a man of writing unnecessarily complicated proofs.

Comment: @KurtG. Let $C := A \times \prod_{i \notin J} \Omega_i$ with $J$ a finite subset of $I$ and $A \in \bigotimes_{i \in J} \mathcal F_i$. Clearly,  $A$ is a subset of the finite Cartesian product $\prod_{i\in I} \Omega_i$. Similarly, $C$ is a subset of the uncountable Cartesian product $\Omega =\prod_{i\in I} \Omega_i$. This implies each $f \in C$ [can be regarded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products) as a map $f:I \to \Omega$ such that $f(i) \in \Omega_i$. So the "order" you referred to is safely keep track by the index sets $I, J$.

Comment: How does the union of $A\times\Omega_\color{red}{2}\times\Omega_3$ and $B\times\Omega_\color{red}{1}\times\Omega_3$ become and element of ${\cal C}$ ? I simply do not get it .

Comment: @KurtG. We have $$
\begin{align}
&A\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_3 \\
= &\{f: I \to \Omega \mid f(1) \in A \text{ and } f(i) \in \Omega_i \text{ for } i \in \{2, 3\}\},
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
&B\times\Omega_1\times\Omega_3 \\
= &\{f: I \to \Omega \mid f(2) \in B \text{ and } f(i) \in \Omega_i \text{ for } i \in \{1, 3\}\}.
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
&(A\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_3) \cup (B\times\Omega_1\times\Omega_3) \\
= &\{f:I \to \Omega \mid (f(1), f(2)) \in (A \times \Omega_2) \cup (\Omega_1 \times B)) \text{ and } f(3) \in \Omega_3\}.
\end{align}
$$