# The product probability measure is unique

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_i, \mathcal{F}_i, \mu_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of probability spaces. Let $\Omega :=\prod_i \Omega_i$. Let $\mathcal F :=\bigotimes_i \mathcal{F}_i$, i.e., $\mathcal F$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that all projection maps $\pi_i: \Omega \to \Omega_i$ are measurable. A measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ is called a *product measure* if with each finite subset $J$ of $I$ and $A_i \in \mathcal F_i$ for $i\in J$, we have
$$
\mu \bigg ( \prod_{i\in J} A_i \times \prod_{i \notin J} \Omega_i \bigg ) = \prod_{i\in J} \mu_i (A_i).
$$

I would like to prove this well-known result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** There is a unique product measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof** I already proved the existence of such a product measure in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551250/the-existence-of-uncountable-product-of-probability-measures?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread. Let's prove the uniqueness part. Let $\mu, \nu$ be two product measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. Then they agree on
$$
\mathcal C := \bigg\{ \prod_i A_i : A_i \in \mathcal F_i, \{i \in I \mid A_i \neq \Omega_i\} \text{ finite}  \bigg\}.
$$

Clearly, $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system. Let
$$
\mathcal D := \{ A \in \mathcal F : \mu(A) = \nu(A) \}.
$$

Then $\mathcal D$ is a $\lambda$-system and $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal D$. By $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, we get $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subset \mathcal D$. As such, $\mathcal D = \mathcal F$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Yes the $\pi, \lambda$ theorem is a good idea for the proof.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: your first identity have two typos: it must be $i\in J$ instead of $i\in I$ in both places

Comment: @Masacroso You're right!

Comment: Any reason for a downvote...?